# IOS swift can I eliminate unused rows in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am using `swift 3.0` and have a `TableView` in it. Everything is working great except that I only have 2 `rows` returning for now, but the `TableView` is showing additional blank rows. I was wondering if there was any way to eliminate those rows?

Below there is how my simple app looks right now: as you can see, I have 2 `rows` and I want to eliminate the other rows, because they do not need to be there. I am new to `TableViews` and I thought that this piece of code controls how many rows should appear:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
   return 2
 }
```

Any suggestions would be great

[image: My TableView]

Answer (score 3):

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIKit` does not create the empty rows when the `tableView` has a `footerView` displayed below the `table cells`. you can add one with `zero height` so its not visible to the user. In the `viewDidLoad` method of your tableView .create a new UIView with a `zero rect frame` and use it to set the `tableFooterView` property of the tableView:

```
yourTableViewName.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give footer to the `UITableView`.
From that your all blank or extra rows are removed.

`on viewDidLoad()` put below code

**Swift 3.0**

```
yourTableViewName.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just add following code on viewDidLoad():**

```
self.tblViewObj.tableFooterView = UIView()
```